# UITableViewCell subclass imageView does not follow the size constraints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a custom table view cell with an image view. In the .xib file, I set the height and width constraint to 23. I then set it to an image.

While using it as a cell, the image does not follow the constraint of 23. I've tried the set the content mode of the UIImageView from scale to fill, to ascpect fit, and various others and nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

[image: My table view cell in xib. Notice the height and width constraints]

[image: The result]

[image: Add the size inspector and constraint]

[image: View debug]
[image: Content mode on the profile image]
[image: Showing that clips to bound and content mode]

Comment: Why do you need it to be 23? Can you set it to a percentage of the cell size? That way no matter what device you load it on, it will scale correctly? What is your tableview cell height?

Comment: table view cell height is 50. Under the cell, the custom is selected and the height is set to 50

Comment: Also, it does not matter what device it is but I want the height to be 50 so the profile image will be right.

Comment: Okay. Can you screenshot the size inspector with the constraints for the image view / their priorities ?

Comment: Does the console prints errors about conflicting constraint? Generally it breaks some when it can't satisfy all of them at the same time.

Comment: I double checked and I don't see any layout constraints errors.

Answer (score 0):

Auto layout may remove constraints as it sees fit if something is clashing with the layout process. IB automatically sets your width and height constraints priority as 1000.  When there are issues and you see that your constraints are being changed, check the debug logs and you will probably see the system added a constraint called UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height and that the system might have also removed some of your constraints.

Try clicking edit next to the height and width constraints in IB and setting their priority to 999 instead of 1000 and see if that remedies your issue.

Comment: Set it height = 23 @999 for both height and width and still does not work. How do I view the debug log?

Comment: I added the view debug and don't see anything that jumps out. It's like the constraints are not applied at all.

Comment: Hmmm what are those two image views at the bottom there? I don't see them in the view controller that contains the table view. Are they just floating? You might have to post your table view code.

Comment: The image view floating at the bottom are tab bar navigations.

Comment: I can share the table view code but it's very standard UITableViewDataSource and Delegate  stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your contentMode is center
try change you imageView's contentMode,like this：

`imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;`

Comment: The content mode is scale to fill. See attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check 'Clips to bound' in IBOutlet and use

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: I already have it set to clips to bounds and also it is set to scale to fill. See the last attached image.

Comment: Just remove Image from ImageView and set a background Color and then check is the same thing happens or imageview looks small as you set. You should confirm that problem is with UIImageView or Image...